How can I control the damage when a game crashes in Lubuntu and ctr-alt-backspace doesn't work?
I'm a new user of Lubuntu, trying out this OS largely because I'm tired of Windows 10's bloatware and hoping to maximize gaming performance. I've been trying games that I didn't think would work before and seeing some promise but both HOI4 and GMod have crashed on me. The first time it happened, I was able to get out after trying ctrl-alt-backspace and Meta-R, at which point it cut to desktop before killing the game. Both times since, nothing worked except for forcing the power off and I'm worried about damaging my system by doing this.
In case it's relevant, I should mention I only got GMod running after setting up proton and I think the crash there could just be routine GMod issues given the number of addons I installed. I've never got HOI4 to the actual gameplay, however. I want to keep experimenting and see what my current set-up is capable of, but I'm worried I'll fry it if I have to keep powering off when it freezes.

You've provided no release details; which is the critical starting point in know what software stack and thus options you have available to you. Rather than power off, your unstated release may allow SysRq commands to safely take back control; or have you tried switching to text terminal & killing/restoring functions/apps that way?  Do note I'm no game player & don't know what HOI4 or GMod is; so its helpful if you're clear & specific rather than using non-Ubuntu terminology.  Did you look up the hotkeys shortcuts for your unstated release in the manual?

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
